# Wrong bookmark text of appendix with scrbook and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, appendices, bookmarks

I'm using [Markus Kohm's fix](http://www.komascript.de/node/1766) to include the prefix "Appendix" also in the table of contents. Unfortunately, this screws up the `bookmarks` (or indices) generated by `hyperref`, as shown in the screenshots below the MWE:

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% From http://www.komascript.de/node/1766
\newcommand*{\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry}{}
\appto\appendixmore{%
  \let\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
  \renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{% Eintrag ohne Nummer
      \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}%
    }{% Eintrag mit Nummer
      \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{%
        \string\expandafter\string\MakeUppercase\string\appendixname
        ~#1\autodot\string\enskip{}#2}%
    }%
  }%
}


\title{Some title}  
\author{Some author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents               

\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{appendix chapter}
\section{Section in appendix}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot from Sumatra (pdfTeX, TeXLive 2015):
[image]

Screenshot from evince (XeTeX, TeXLive 2013):
[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: The `\string\expandafter\...` line is of no meaning to the pdf viewer, because it's partially unexpandable LaTeX code and can't be understood as a `bookmark` entry. You need `\texorpdfstring{texcontent}{pdfcontent}` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\string\expandafter\...` line is of no meaning to the pdf viewer, because it's partially unexpandable LaTeX code (`\MakeUppercase` is the villain here!) and can't be understood as a bookmark entry. You need `\texorpdfstring{texcontent}{pdfcontent}` for this.

I've wrapped `\texorpdfstring{...}{...}` around the offending line and use `\appendixname` for the `pdfcontent` part -- `\appendixname` is expandable and replaced by `Appendix` (in English language settings)

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% From http://www.komascript.de/node/1766
\newcommand*{\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry}{}
\appto\appendixmore{%
  \let\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
  \renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{% Eintrag ohne Nummer
      \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}%
    }{% Eintrag mit Nummer
      \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{%
        \texorpdfstring{\string\expandafter\string\MakeUppercase\string\appendixname
        ~#1\autodot\string\enskip{}#2}{\appendixname}}%
    }%
  }%
}


\title{Some title}  
\author{Some author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents               

\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{appendix chapter}
\section{Section in appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The question is, if this is really needed to make it that complicated or is this an old fix to some older KOMA setup?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[appendixprefix]{scrbook}

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\appendix{%
  \renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{
    \ifstr{#1}{}{%
      \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{#2}%
    }{%
      \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\chapapp~#1: #2}%
    }%
  }
}

\title{Some title}  
\author{Some author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Some chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix chapter}
\section{Section in first appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix chapter}
\section{Section in second appendix}
%
\addchap{Chapter without number}

\end{document}
```